# Android LinearLayout Align Right

Tags: android, css

I've speech bubbles and the gravity of the speech bubbles are center. 
If I write a message the adapter set the gravity to left or right but the speech bubbles always left.

```
bubble.setGravity(chatMessageObj.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/speechbubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`layout_gravity` != `gravity`

Layout gravity is with respect to parent; gravity is with respect to content. So `layout_gravity` center, will always position the view within its parent's center; while `gravity` `LEFT` or `RIGHT` will position the content within that view to the left or right.

One problem with your code is the parent `LinearLayout` has no orientation!

What does the rest of this layout look like? Or is this `linearlayout bubble` the only other view in it?

Comment: I tried to set gravity of the textview to right but it's not work. :(

Comment: The bubble is the linear Layout

Answer (score 1):

Try using LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = chatMessageObj.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT;
bubble.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the layout_width from the second LinearLayout to wrap_content and the gravity (not layout_gravity) from first LinearLayout to right. It is work now!